# Can't find npm packages in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, npm-install, typescript-typings

I'm trying to install npm package '@types/angular' as showed below to my asp mvc project.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/angular

Have tried the following but my **IDE can't seems to find the npm package**.

Include "@types/angular" in the package.json in Visual Studio 2017. VS shows "Unavailable" for the package.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "angular": "^1.6.4"
  }
}
```

BUT it works if I perform '**npm install --save @types/angular**' from CLI. The package is installed and the package.json is updated as well.

I wish to have the CLI experience within my VS, **what is missing in my VS setup**?

Comment: Turns out VS2017 does not provide intellisense of @types packages. We have to check the latest version of the desired package on https://www.npmjs.com/ and then key in manually in the package.json file. Installation will still commence and works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use package manger console in vs 2015 or later from Tools -> NuGet package manager -> package manager console 
In the console type your command and it will be downloaded to your project

Comment: Tried that but it's trying to look for package.json in the root (aka solution) folder instead of the project folder. I have the target folder selected in the console. Any idea how to install only to the project instead of installing it to the root folder?

Comment: this command installs it in the project folder correctly but there is an error message appears I don't know why! so I opened an issue in the module repo in GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/16404)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Tools > Node.js Tools > Node.js Interactive Window

in there type
.npm install package_name

Answer (score 0):

Go to the ClientApp folder where the package.json file exists.

Then open "windows PowerShell as administrator" from this directory.
[this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK4j5.jpg)

write this code in order to run npm.

```
npm start
```

If everything goes well you get such an output. "compiled successfully."

[this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39jQ0.png)
Now you can run your project in visual studio.